# Watchkit - shared code - framework, app extension, app groups, add target or just copy files?

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit

I have an existing app and I'm adding a Watch app to it. I have several .swift files with code from my main app that I'll need to use for the watchkit app (functions and some constants, etc). I'm confused by the options for sharing this code - how do I know which one to try and use?

Create an app group, my own framework, app extension? I actually started to just copy the .swift files into my watchkit app folder and noticed when you add a file to Xcode on the dialog that comes up you get the check boxes of "Add to targets" so that got me thinking - is there a way to just change the properties of my .swift files in the main app section and check off the WatchKit App on the "Add to Targets" there?

That seems like it would be the way to go, right?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved that Just clicking on the files and add them in both targets. (iphone app target and apple watch extension target).

To fix the sharedapplication problem I used this:

```
#if (SL_TARGET_APP_EXTENSION == NO)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] .....
#endif
```

SL_TARGET_APP_EXTENSION  is a preprocessor macro added in the apple watch extension target.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying this and run into an issue with this line of code in one of the files I added to the watch extension target:

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
 
- it gives me the error "sharedApplication() is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.  I'm reading up about this now..bah

Comment: So I guess that means for your app you didn't need the sharedApplication for the watch app? What do I do if I need that?

Comment: You can't, look at this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6

"Access a sharedApplication object, and so cannot use any of the methods on that object "

Comment: I only use this sharedApplication for deleting objects from core data. Is this what you happen to use it for too? What did you do to go around this issue?

Comment: This library uses coredata in watchkit and does not access to sharedApplicaton:  https://github.com/aalittle/CoreDataWatchKit
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much, Javier. That's a great example with a nice little 10 minute video to go with it. And apparently the answer to my original question is "you won't be choosing one of those methods but you'll need to use pretty much all of them." For anyone stuck on this just watch the video and you'll see what I mean (this is the youtube that goes with the github Javier linked above - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vR0d7jTuxo&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

To share code between an apple watch app and your main app, you'll need to create a framework with that shared code. You said it yourself, an apple watch app is an entirely new target - it's not going to know squat about your existing code.

Creating an app group, you can also share `NSUserDefaults:` using `initWithSuiteName` and for Coredata, you can go the shared container route.

Comment: Ok, gotcha - thank you. To help me understand though - why can't I just add the watchkit extension to the files' "Target Membership"?

Comment: Never mind this comment question, I get it now - you were right. I just didn't have all the pieces yet. Thank you very much.