# WatchKit "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when trying to fire an NSTimer object in Swift

Tags: animation, watchkit, unrecognized-selector

In my WatchKit extensions InterfaceController.swift file I call a function, from within the awakeWithContext function, that runs an animated sequence of images.

I have used an NSTimer object to time a delay and then fire off a second animated sequence.

`var nsTimerObject:NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(showCodeDelay, target: self, selector: "showCode(counterCode1)", userInfo: nil, repeats: false);`

After the first animation runs I get an error preventing the second animation being fired by the function specified in the **selector**:

> [Code_Break_WatchKit_Extension.InterfaceController showCode(counterCode1)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800014c3f0

I have the iOS Device App and the WatchKit extension ticked in the **Target Membership**

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498214/watchkit-image-animation-wait-for-finish) on stack**overflow** which sent me down this route.

Another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494040/watchkit-shared-code-framework-app-extension-app-groups-add-target-or-jus) seemed to suggest I may need to do something around "Sharing" but it was unclear.

It feels like it should be simple but I'm stumped.

I am new to this so please be gentle on me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it!

The problem was in the syntax for setting the **selector** function and passing the parameters required for the function to work.

I changed:

```
var nsTimerObject:NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(showCodeDelay, target: self, selector: "showCode(counterCode1)", userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
```

to:

```
var nsTimerObject:NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(showCodeDelay, target: self, selector: "showCode:", userInfo: counterCode1, repeats: false);
```

Then I had to alter my showCodeDelay function declaration from:

```
func showCodeDelay(counterCode: Int){

//code........
}
```

to:

```
func showCodeDelay(nsTimerObject:NSTimer){
        var tempCounterCode = nsTimerObject.userInfo as! NSNumber
        var counterCode = Int(tempCounterCode)

        //code........
}
```

I'm just getting my head around it I wrongly first thought that I was simply pointing the **selector** at the function I had created with its required parameters.

However it looks like when taking this approach the function being referred to in the **selector** has to receive the actual NSTimer object and from this extract the parameters required from the **userInfo**

Once I'd figured this out the next problem I had was extracted the value I had passed in **userInfo** because Xcode wanted me treat it as an **AnyObject!** that can't be expressed as an **Int** so I extracted **userInfo** from the **nsTimerObject** object as an **NSNumber** and then downcast this to an **Int**

There may be a simpler more elegant way to achieve the downcast but at least this worked.